# Can I use a button top open other layouts on FileMaker Pro?

Tags: filemaker

I want to open other layouts using buttons on FileMaker Pro. I don't see a command or controls when I double click on the button from edit mode. Do I have to write a script or something? Please help I am fairly new to FileMaker Pro!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Go to Layout[]` command/script step:
http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref1.36.20.html#1028245